# How to turn off save prompt when closing Sketchup

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I'm using sketchup with a plugin, which makes custom files. The users of this plugin never need to save their files of .skp files, and if they do it will confuse them.

When closing Sketchup, there is a prompt to save the model, which would result in saving a .skp file, which is not desired. There is a `Sketchup::AppObserver.onQuit()`, but that doesn't full my purpose -- I'm looking for something more like `Sketchup::AppObserver.beforeQuit()`

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Model.close](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/model#close), which has a parameter to ignore changes. Then quitting the program should not prompt. However, this is only available in SketchUp 2015 and later.

Edit: I guess you want to do this when the user quits and not force a quit. So this may not be answering your question exactly.

Comment: Yeah that won't work for me...I know how to force sketchup to close with now save prompt (just execute `exit!` in Ruby), but the real question is how do we tie into the handler that handles the user clicking the 'X' button in the Sketchup Window.